# Nested routes form_for partial not working for new and edit actions - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I used the generator to scaffold categories and questions.

my routes.rb

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :questions do
      resources :choices, only: [:index]
    end
  end
```

my problem occurs when i try to add or edit a question.

here is my partial form, *before you ask the relationship works ok*.

```
<%= form_for [@question.category, @question] do |f| %>
  <% if @question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :question_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :explanation %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :explanation %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

what must i change for it to work? for now i get,

```
undefined method `questions_path'
```

Comment: can you show your `category` and `question` models?

Comment: category model only has `has_many :questions` , and question model has `belongs_to :category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**UPDATE**

Controller

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
@question = @category.questions.new
```

_form

```
<%= form_for([@category, @question]) do |f| %>
```

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: make a slight edit, params should be category_id and i should mark it as correct. this is what worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `category.rb` model file:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

Also, in your controller:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
@question = Question.new(category: @category)
```

and form:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @question]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: getting this, `No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>nil, :controller=>"questions", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:category_id, :id]` for some reason the category_id is not passed. But when i try through the console `question.category` i have access to the category

Comment: try my updated answer. Just add that line to your `category` model and try without changing your form_for

Comment: thank you, your answer is the same i just wanted to tell you that i have tried without `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` and it still works thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. So, it might be useful to you as you are working with nested resources. Check this out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: thank you i am reading through what you gave me i just do not get the whole picture yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass parent and then build child for same for new object.

```
<%= form_for [@category, @category.questions.build] do |f| %>
```

To edit:

```
<%= form_for [@category, @category.questions.first_or_your_object] do |f| %>
```

Like this :

```
<% if @category.new_record? %>
  <%= form_for [@category, @category.questions.build] do |f| %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for [@category, @category.questions.first_or_your_object] do |f|
<% else %>
```

Also add in your category model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

Comment: I think you got it the other way around, i had problems creating questions not categories.

Comment: It was not mention in your question. But finally you got your answer that's great.

Comment: yeah i didnt because the partial speaks for itself :) thank you for the effort though, appreciated!